# What is the extension signature for this .encode?

Tags: swift, class, swift5

I am encoding all objects of a core data entity to JSON.

I have these lines on the core data entity extension...

```
public func encode(to encoder:Encoder) throws {
  var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
  try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
  ...
}
```

I would like to create an extension for the `.encode` part on the `container.encode` part, so I can intercept it and change as I like..

I see this `.encode` has the following signature

```
public mutating func encode<T>(_ value: T, forKey key: KeyedEncodingContainer<K>.Key) throws where T : Encodable
```

ant that this belongs to

```
public struct KeyedEncodingContainer<K> : KeyedEncodingContainerProtocol where K : CodingKey {
```

If I want to override this `encode` of `KeyedEncodingContaine`r, how should I write the extension header?

This is me blindly showing what I need...

```
extension KeyedEncodingContainer<K> : KeyedEncodingContainerProtocol where K : CodingKey {
  override func encode<T>(_ value: T, forKey key: Self.Key) throws where T : Encodable
    // stuff here
  }
}
```

In other words, I need to replace that `encode` with mine. Is that possible?

According to @shadowrun, I cannot extend that, because it is a struct.

So, suppose I create a class called `EncodingNormalized` like this one that is incorrect.

```
class EncodingNormalized {
  class func encode(container:KeyedEncodingContainer<Key> where Key : CodingKey) {
  }
}
```

I still need the class and the func encode signatures. Not that easy.

Comment: KeyedEncodingContainer is a struct, there's no inheritance - what are you wanting to do - why are you wanting to override encode?

Comment: because I want to intercept the value as it is being encoded to change the format to what I want. Example: dates are being encoded as numbers and I need them as string with a specific format. Ok, suppose I create a class to do this, again, what is the class signature?

Comment: I have added more stuff to the question.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you asked one question at a time? This seems to be much the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66889363/how-to-change-the-json-encoding-of-a-coredata-entity-to-what-i-need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> because I want to intercept the value as it is being encoded to change the format to what I want. Example: dates are being encoded as numbers and I need them as string with a specific format.

If you're dealing with a `JSONEncoder`, set the `dateEncodingStrategy` on the encoder to give you dates in the format you want.

If you're not dealing with `JSONEncoder`, and you're also dealing with other custom formatting things other than dates, then you do it manually inside the `encode(to: )` implementation (e.g. convert something else to a string, then encode the string).

Comment: Your last paragraph: my point is that the entity contains 70 fields (don't ask me why, I have not designed it) and all fields may be null. So doing 70 checks to see if a field is null and if not, to see if it is a date, a bool or a string and acting properly will generate 1 trillion lines of code. If I can have a method I can call on every item and just design it once. No way to do that?

Comment: A managed object has an `entity` which contains descriptions of each property and type, if they are optional, what property type they are and so forth. Feels like that would be a good thing to use for a smart encode(to:) method.

Comment: Presumably you're already having to write tons of code to describe coding keys to match each attribute and so on... you don't have to do that if you can leverage the entity description. But none of this was in your question, it's always best to describe what you want to do rather than how you think it ought to be done.